# Class file not imported in the same module

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ and I have project with module called "customers", now inside this module
there is a src, testsrc and web folder. Now the src folder is marked as  "Source folder",
"testsrc" and "web\testSrc" are marked as Test folders and the web folder is not marked with anything. In this module I am trying from the class located at the `testsrc` folder
:`com.loyalty.constants.MyTest.java` to import the class from the `web` folder : `com.data.v2.controller.MyController.java` and I did this by selecting the folder where the .class file is generated for MyController.java in IntelliJ idea, however during `ant all` I get an exception that MyTest.java cannot import MyController.java because it doesn't know it exists. Importing jars and modules seems fine, but importing folders containing .class files results in the .class not being able to be recognized. Any suggestions or tips how can I solve this issue or where the problem it might be? I have tried invalidating caches but it didnt't work, also I tried reimporting the project again in IntelliJ .

Comment: Please provide the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).